# populate multiple drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

i have 3 table in database that must be displayed  in 3 drop list using php and mysql  but these three table go like this user select from the first one then the second drop list will display data based on the selection of the first and the third based on the selection of the second ...
my question is what is better

using three different tables   country district village
  or just one that contain all the data

can anyone help me ??
 i can populate the tree table but independent from each other

## these are 2 queries

```
function districtQuery(){

$distData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM districts");

  while($recorddist = mysql_fetch_array($distData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recorddist['district_name'] .  '">' . $recorddist['district_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
// function for select by village
function villageQuery(){

//$villageData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM village");

  $villageData = mysql_query("SELECT village_name FROM village INNER JOIN districts ON village.district_id = districts.district_id") or die (mysql_error());

  while($recordvillage = mysql_fetch_array($villageData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordvillage['village_name'] .  '">' . $recordvillage['village_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Populated Drop Down List PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727311/dynamic-populated-drop-down-list-php-mysql)

Comment: this can be done with PHP, it's usually done with JS / jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you divide your tables into three different tables and link them...This will give you more control and flexibility over your data and allow you to write queries easily. Below is an example.

```
//Country Table
id, country_name 

//District Table
id, country_id, name

//Village Table
id, country_id, district_id, name
```

Comment: @  jay Bhatt yess that what i did but the problem that i want to make the selection of the second table based on the selection of the first .. and this is what i am unable to make it successfully

Comment: If the selection is based on the district, you can write following query, Select d.name, v.name from district as d, village as v where v.district_id = d.id and d.id = 'Id passed from your dropdown';